# Using access database in php

Tags: php, ms-access

I built a stock manager on VB.NET, it uses a MS Access Database. I also built a website, and on this website I want to relularly upload the updated MS Access database file onto the website and insert it into the mySql Database. Now my problem is I dont know how to access the MS Access file using php, im sure theres a way without buying those softwares, but i cant find it. Now I not bound to this scenario, if someone has better ideas i would appreciate it, most importantly I want the stock management to be offline, and at the end of the day, i want it uploaded to the site.
Thanks alot

Comment: I would probably consider writing an updater in VB.Net that simply takes the Access data and dumps it into a MySQL database right from the desktop instead of uploading the Access database.

Answer (score 2):

I have done that in the past using ADODB and JET:

```
// connect
$conn = new COM('ADODB.Connection');
$conn->Open("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={$database};Mode=ReadWrite;");

//query
$results = $conn->Execute($sql);

// retrieve
$results->Fields[$field]->Value;

// navigation
$results->MoveNext();
$results->Move($count);
$results->EOF();

// Close (don't forget)
$conn->Close();
```

This is just a small sample. [More Help](http://www.w3schools.com/ado/ado_ref_connection.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Look into `php_odbc` which has the ability to communicate with MS Access if you have correctly configured an ODBC data source on the PHP server. [`php_odbc` documentation here.](http://php.net/manual/en/book.uodbc.php)

```
// From the `odbc_connect()` documentation:
// Microsoft Access
$connection = odbc_connect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};Dbq=$mdbFilename", $user, $password);
```