# How to read and write into access database with PHP

Tags: php, ms-access

How to read and write into a MS Access database with PHP.

I need just general explanation and code. I have experience with PHP and MySQL, but never writing to an Access database.

Comment: check [Using Access Database in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6062033/using-access-database-in-php) and [PHP and MS Access](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114996/php-and-ms-access) questions on SO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to use ODBC. Some helpful information may be found on [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.uodbc.php) or [this article with examples](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_db_odbc.asp).