# Reading An Access Database File With Zend

Tags: php, zend-framework, ms-access

I have to create a system where the user will select an access database file from his pc and the data will have to be read from that file and inserted to an oracle database. I am using zend framework.Can anybody give any suggestion on where to start.Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You'll want connections to the access database using php. [W3Schools on connecting to ODBC](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_db_odbc.asp) and [StackOverflow connecting to Access databases with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6062033/using-access-database-in-php)
- You'll want to open a connection to your oracle database and write to it. [PHP Manual on connecting to Oracle via php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-connect.php)
- Then you'll want to query both databases, you can use PDO if you are working in php. [PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/)